# Intellij IDEA 9: How can I disable the highlighting of errors in HTML files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, error-reporting

How can I disable the highlighting of errors in HTML files in Intellij IDEA 9?

Comment: I'm interested in this too, but in disabling error highlighting on a file-by-file basis, not globally. I have a deliberately error-filled HTML file which is test input for an HTML parser, and I'd prefer that the deliberate errors in this file are ignored when checking my full project for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings (ctrl+shift+s). and then search for errors. Under inspections, find HTML tree node and then uncheck the root. No more HTML validation.

Comment: In Intellij 10, I did this but the highlighting of errors remained.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and disabling inspection does not help. Tried IDE restart and reopening of project, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Editor -> Inspections (Ctrl + Alt + S)

You need to uncheck everything related. Even when you have HTML document, it may contain some CSS for example, so switching off just HTML won't suffice. Make sure you do that, apply and see for yourselves.